# Creating Setter with boundaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, variables, setter

Inside a class, I use a variable such as a percentage and I want it to have some boundaries. For example: I want the value between 0 and 100. If the value is set to 105, then the value stored would be 100.

I first implemented this:

```
var percentage: Int{
    set{
        if (newValue < 0) {
            self.percentage = 0
        } else if (newValue > 100) {
            self.percentage = 100
        } else {
            self.percentage = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error due to an infinite loop on the setter. Looking for a solution, I've found two different approaches:

**First approach using two variables:**

```
var percentageWithBoundaries: Int

var percentageWithoutBoundaries: Int{
    get{
        return percentageWithBoundaries
    }
    set{
        if (newValue < 0) {
            percentageWithBoundaries = 0
        } else if (newValue > 100) {                     
            percentageWithBoundaries = 100
        } else {
            percentageWithBoundaries = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

**Second approach using didSet:**

```
var percentage: Int{
    didSet{
        if (percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0
        } else if (percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the second approach is better: more concise and easier to understand.

I would like to know if there's a better practice or if one of this two ones should be preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: Using `didSet` is definitely the right approach for what you want.

Comment: Thanks but can you give some explanation why for you it should be the best approach?

Comment: Just because it's the simplest and the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var percentage: Int{
    didSet{
        if (percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0
        } else if (percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is best to set variable with conditions.

Comment: Any explanation why?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code like this or according to your needs;

> **willSet** is called just before the value is stored.
>
> **didSet** is called immediately after the new value is stored.

```
var percentage: Int = 0{
    didSet{
        if (percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0
        } else if (percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the else statement necessary as the value will already have been stored?

Comment: @Jojo44 I modified code with new one. No there is no need to else statement.

Comment: Ok, then I don't see the difference with my second approach code... :/